# how to use StandardEnvironment in a plan java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, config

When I read the spring source code, I find the class StandardEnvironment. I want to use  StandardEnvironment in a  plan java application as follows。 But It is wrong.

```
@Test
public void test() {

     StandardEnvironment enviment=new StandardEnvironment();
            System.out.println(enviment.getProperty("Pk")==null?"not find":enviment.getProperty("Pk"));


}
```

```
java.lang.Exception: No tests found matching [{ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test], {ExactMatcher:fDisplayName=test(com.dominos.cloud.user.dao.EnvimentTest)], {LeadingIdentifierMatcher:fClassName=com.dominos.cloud.user.dao.EnvimentTest,fLeadingIdentifier=test]] from org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest@2acf57e3
    at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createFilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Comment: All code like this:

Comment: `code`                                                                                                                                   
         public class EnvimentTest {

 
 @Test
 public void test() {
  
   StandardEnvironment enviment=new StandardEnvironment();
    System.out.println(enviment.getProperty("Pk")==null?"没有值":enviment.getProperty("Pk"));
      
  
 }
 
}

Comment: Please go through this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40863593/4214241)

Comment: @lipeng Please update the question with the complete code instead if writing in comment. It will be much more readable in the question.